# Reach item within a list within another list and assign them values

Tags: c#, list, xml-serialization

I have a `List<NXRoute>`, each `NXRoute` also contains a `List<Path>`

there are my classes definitions :

```
[XmlRoot("NXRoutes")]
public class NXRoutes
{
    [XmlElement("NXRoute")]
    public List<NXRoute> NXRoute { get; set; }
}

public class NXRoute
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("OriginSignal")]
    public string OriginSignal { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("DestinationSignal")]
    public string DestinationSignal { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Path")]
    public List<Path> Path { get; set; }
}

public class Path
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Preferred")]
    public string Preferred { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("SnowPlan")]
    public string SnowPlan { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string PathInnerText { get; set; }
}
```

I will use these in XmlSerialization to generate a xml file

in order to assign values to the attributes (ID, Preferred ...etc),
How can I reach the 'path' list's elements ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the collections to access each `Path` instance

**Access values or set values on an existing instance**

```
NXRoutes routes = new NXRoutes();

foreach (var route in routes.NXRoute)
{
  foreach (var path in route.Path)
  {
     path.ID = 5;
     path.Preferred = "preferred";
     path.SnowPlan = "plan"
  }
}
```

**Set values for a new instance**

```
NXRoutes routes = getRoutes();
routes.NXRoute = new List<NXRoute>()
{
  new NXRoute { ID = 1, OrginSignal = "value", Path = new List<Path>() 
               {
                 new Path { ID = 1, Preferred = "value", SnowPlan = "plan" },
                 new Path { ID = 2, Preferred = "value", SnowPlan2 = "plan2" }
               }
              },
  new NXRoute { ID = 2, OrginSignal = "value"  Path = new List<Path>() 
              { 
               new Path { ID = 3, Preferred = "value", SnowPlan3 = "plan4" },
               new Path { ID = 4, Preferred = "value", SnowPlan4 = "plan4" }
              },
 }
}
```

Comment: @Bruce I have tried the foreach loop and I'm getting an exception :

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

ReadXmlFile.NXRoute.Path.get returned null.
`

Comment: please post your code so we can see what you're doing